# How to use separable filter shaders in OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to use shaders for image processing in my iOS app. I can use one pair of shaders(vertex and fragment) for filter image (for example vertical or horizontal blur), but how about if I need to firstly apply vertical blur and then apply horizontal blur. How should I link this actions in my `render()` function?

Some code example would be excellent!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not really much you can do. You need the buffer to be filled from one step of the blur before starting the next step. The best thing you can do is draw to texture with first pass and then redraw with the second pass to the main buffer. In general if you have more then 2 passes you will need 2 textures which then swap after every pass: Draw image with first shader to texture1, second from texture1 to texture2, third from texture2 to texture1...

So what you need is a frame buffer object (FBO) which means simply generating a new frame buffer and a texture with a desired size (you will most likely need to use a POT texture), attach the texture to the frame buffer as a color attachment `glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, targetTexture, 0);`.

After this is done you are left with pretty much standard drawing procedure. Simply bind this frame buffer to draw to it, set the viewport, set the matrices if any... All will be drawn to the texture as if it was the main buffer.

Once you are done with drawing to the texture you can use that texture to draw it back to your main buffer. Simply bind the main buffer and bind the texture from the FBO instead the one from the original image. Rest of the code should be the same.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I tried this approach and it works perfectly! But my resulting image is rotated 90 degrees. I think it occurs because of my VBOs. Should I re-setup VBOs too?

Comment: Since you probably rotate the image already in your single pass drawing what you did was rotate it again in the FBO pass. It would probably be best to setup a different vertex buffer and possibly even the matrices if any so the texture simply fills the FBO. So yes, create another VBO for the offscreen rendering.

Comment: Thank you, it works! But could you please tell me where should I free textures and frame buffers memory in that case. Thanks!

Comment: As soon as possible or rather as soon as you are sure you do not need them. You should have enough memory not to worry too much about it in your case. So if you can reuse the FBO textures for next frames you should only delete textures on resize or when the scene is not needed anymore. The frame buffer is not memory intense, it holds no data by itself but holds a collection of render buffers and textures. You may simply detach the texture and attach another. But try not to create textures on every frame. If the frame keeps changing use a very large texture and keep reusing it.

Comment: Thank you for detail answer again! I realized this method for 2 iterations. (vertical and horizontal blurs) and this works fine, but now I'm trying to realize this for filter with 3 iterations using the same idea. It compiles but crashes in the last line of render()-function in glDeleteTextures() line. I so confused! Have you any idea about this?

Comment: I would need more information to help you with that one. For 3 passes you still need just 2 textures. Do not delete them but rather reuse them.